# align text to the top of the div

Tags: html, css

Hi all on my page here: http://www.gamingonlinux.com/sales/ i want to align text in the added, price, savings and provider to the top, how would I go about that?

Here is the html for the columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">
        {:screenshot} {:info}
    </div>
    <div class="date-column">
        {:date}
    </div>
    <div class="price-column">
        {:price}
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        {:savings}
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        {:provider}
    </div>
</div>
```

And their css:

```
.left
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 14px;
}

.price-column
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 150px;
}

.date-column
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 150px;
}

.middle
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 75px;
    padding: 14px;
}

.right
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 155px;
    padding: 14px;
}
```

Inside the "left" div the screenshot and name are inside floated left and right spans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like on a regular table cell you can use `vertical-align:top;` to do the alignment.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered if this answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add  float: left; to your css (.left class) like this

```
.left
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 14px;
    float: left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:

```
.row > div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem try this code. `vertical-align` is good choice:

```
display: table-cell;
padding: 10px;
width: 150px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top;
```

More other options for `vertical-align` is:

[image]

[image]